# Update one dictionary with another in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to send a dictionary key through command line. `sys.argv[1]` has the key.
This key is store in `var2` and send to `append_func` which is a another file append.
dynamically whenever I give command line arguments for key, I want dictionary to get appended. But its overwriting everytime when ever i enter new commandline argument

Please look at the code :

```
##filename : dictionary.py## 

import sys
import append
dic={}
var1=sys.argv[0]
var2=sys.argv[1]
dicto=append.append_fun(var2,dic)
dic=dic.update(dicto)
print dic

##filename : append.py##
def append_fun(var2,dic1):
    dic1[var2] = "hello"
    return dic1
```

In the command line i am calling `dictionary.py test`. Again when i call, `dictionary.py  test1` it does not append `dic` with both values, it will overwrite with second one.

Please help me how to append `dic` dictionary

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: i run dictionary.py file as follows:

dictionary.py test

dictionary.py test1

i want to get output {test : hello, test1 : hello}

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29), so that you can call:

```
python dictionary.py test
```

And then later execute again:

```
python dictionary.py test1
```

whilst having the results from the first run remain.  But nowhere are you saving the data from the first run, and it can not work like this currently because of the line `dic={}` which is executed each time initialising the empty dict.

To get this you will need to save state somewhere, say in a temporary file or a database.  Instead of the line `dic={}`, your code must reload the previous state at startup (and, of course, you must also dump the current state before exit).

I recommend taking a look at [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for a simple and easy serialization of python objects to disk.

Comment: it does not have duplicate keys.. each time i run dictionary.py with different strings.
for ex: dictionary.py test1 
        dictionary.py test
output should be : {test1 : hello, test : hello}

Comment: Oh right, you want it to be persistent over different executions of the python file?

Comment: yes.. key will keep changing at run time and value will be same.

accordingly i want dictionary to get updated

Comment: ok.. in dictionary.py i have written
    dicto=append.append_fun(var2,dic)
    dic=dic.update(dicto)

so whatever key value pair returned from append.append_fun(var2,dic) is stored in dicto.

and when i do,

    dic=dic.update(dicto) shouldn't it not work?

Comment: Nope, you still aren't saving information so state will be lost when python interpreter exist.

Answer (score 1):

Before we get around to your question, you should really take this code to codereview.stackexchange.com . I find it difficult to understand why you preferred

```
dicto=append.append_fun(var2,dic)
```

to

```
dicto[var2] = "hello"
```

If I am understanding you correctly, you would like a dictionary that, when you assign to it, appends the assigned value to any others that may have already been stored against that key? If so, are you going to love [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). I hope. Though it won't quite do that, I think it's capable of providing you with what they want.

When you create a `defaultdict` you call the class with one argument, a function that will be called to create a new value when an absent key is retrieved. Since `list()` returns an empty list attempting to retrieve any key will cause that key to be created and associated with a value created by calling the default object function (the one that was provided as an argument at object instantiation time). I hope the following interactive session will explain what you need to know, but if not see the documentation I linked to.

```
>>> import collections
>>> mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> mydict['newkey'].append("Surprise!") # empty list invisibly created
>>> mydict['newkey']
['Surprise!']
>>> mydict['newkey'].append("Surprise again!")
>>> mydict['newkey']
['Surprise!', 'Surprise again!']
>>> mydict['no such key']
[]
>>> list(mydict.keys())
['no such key', 'newkey']
>>>
```

Does this help, or have I been barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

In python dictionary are mutable object. Therefore, modification are done "in place". So you write

```
dic.update(dicto)
```

because `update` doesn't return anything. In the same vein:

```
def append_fun(var2,dic1):
    dic1[var2] = "hello"
```

and

```
append.append_fun(var2,dic)
```

Comment: append_fun(var2,dic1) returns the key value. But in dictionary.py when i do dic=dic.update(dicto) . it does not append to the already existing key value pair in dic

it has only the one key value pair returned from append_fun